# spark sql current timestamp function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a sql fucntion in spark sql which returns back current timestamp , example in impala NOW() is the function which returns back current timestamp is there similar in spark sql ?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try current_timestamp function.

```
current_timestamp() - Returns the current timestamp at the start of query evaluation. All calls of current_timestamp within the same query return the same value.
```

Comment: got it I missed () at the end of the function ...,https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights-datetimestring-handling-time-intervals-and-udafs.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Date and Timestamp functions from pyspark sql functions.

Example:

```
spark-sql> select current_timestamp();
2022-05-07 16:43:43.207
Time taken: 0.17 seconds, Fetched 1 row(s)
spark-sql> select current_date();
2022-05-07
Time taken: 5.224 seconds, Fetched 1 row(s)
spark-sql>
```

Reference:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp.html

Comment: this is a 6-year-old question :-) not sure what has caused it to re appear

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the date and timestamp in Spark with Scala code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDf = df.withColumn("current_date",current_date())
.withColumn("current_timestamp",current_timestamp())
```

The result will be something like this.

```
+------------+-----------------------+
|current_date|current_timestamp      |
+------------+-----------------------+
|2022-06-06  |2022-06-06 12:25:55.349|
+------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: this is 6-year-old question :-) not sure what has caused it to re appear